# Do fractional exponents make sense?

Tags: exponentiation

**According to my resources,** $\sqrt x = x^{\frac{1}{2}}$, and $\sqrt[3] x = x^{\frac{1}{3}}$, etc, or to put it simply, $\sqrt[y] x = x^{\frac{1}{y}}$.

However, since I understand an exponent to mean the amount of times a given number (`x` in this example) is multiplied by itself, I'm not sure if this way of displaying exponents makes sense.

After all, if $x^3$ is shorthand for $x\times x\times x$ and $x^4$ is shorthand for $x\times x\times x\times x$, wouldn't $x^{\frac{1}{2}}$ be the same thing as $x \over 2$? (I say this because if the exponent refers to the quantity of times `x` is multiplied by itself, at first glance, it seems like $x^{\frac{1}{2}}$ would *(maybe?)* mean $x\over2$ ... ?)

---

**On the other hand,** since $x^y \times x^z = x^{y+z}$ we can see that $x^{\frac{1}{2}} \times x^{\frac{1}{2}} = x$ which is what we would expect. If you think about it this way, it makes perfect sense (yea, it's expected) that $x^{\frac{1}{y}} = \sqrt[y] x$.

---

**I realize that this is a rather basic question,** so why would I ask it?

Well, the beauty of mathematics [(versus, English's grammar rules, perhaps)](http://www.ibeforee.org) is that *numbers make sense!* Hence, there's no reason why you shouldn't be able to understand why something works in math.
<sub>(Thank God numbers aren't arbitrary!)</sub>

Hence, I'd like to be able to understand why $\sqrt[y] x$ can be written as $x^{\frac{1}{y}}$. One more thing, according to my calculator $x^{1.5} \times x^{1.5} = x^3 = 125$, why does $x^{1.5} = x \times x^{\frac{1}{2}}$?

---

**I guess my basic question is somewhere along the lines of:** "$\sqrt[y] x = x^{1/y}$ feels arbitrary (except for the point about adding exponents made above). Why isn't it arbitrary?"

Is it because since $\sqrt x \times \sqrt x = x$ and we know that we add the exponents when multiplying, $\sqrt x$ must be the same as $x^{\frac{1}{2}}$ since this allows us to multiply the square roots, adding $^{\frac{1}{2}}$ to $^{\frac{1}{2}}$ thus getting $x^1$ which is the correct answer?

---

<sub>**PS:** Did I just answer my own question in a rather informal, unstandardized way?</sub>

Comment: Fractional exponents always make sense, even when $x$ is negative - provided, of course, you go into complex numbers... and what you ask about follows from the rules of exponents.

Comment: I think you not only answered your own question, but that the answer you gave was *the* standard way. You want the arithmetic with exponents to mimic the arithmetic of nth roots: just as you said when you wrote "on the other hand since..." I am not sure if there is anything else to say, other than this is why we define fractional (and negative) exponents this way.

Comment: @User0112358: Thanks. That makes sense. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two reasons. First, chained exponentiation follows the rule:$$ \left(x^y\right)^z = x^{yz}.$$ So, if $y= 1/z$ then $\left(x^y\right)^z = x$, meaning that exponentiation by the reciprocal obeys the property that defines taking a root.

Second, if you want to know how these things are actually calculated, that's an interesting question, too. We can define two functions [$\operatorname{e}^x$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponential_function) and it's functional inverse [$\ln x$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Natural_logarithm) (that is $\operatorname{e}^{\ln x} = \ln [\operatorname{e}^x] = x$) in terms of power series. $\ln x$, in particular, has the property:
$$\ln x^y = y\ln x,$$
making it possible to calculate $x^y$ using the identity:
$$x^y = \operatorname{e}^{y\ln x}.$$
I don't think that this is how it is actually calculated by computers, because this way is probably pretty slow, but it can be done this way.

Comment: Thanks, Sean. The chained exponentiation was what I was trying to say in my post, but didn't quite know how to say. :) +!